# Drone CI ECR Plugin - Cannot connect to docker daemon

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, drone.io

I have a drone server and runner running on an EC2 machine, seems to be working fine until the publish to ECR step. I keep running into the error in the screenshot below:

[image]

Below is the code for the publish step in my drone.yml, any help is much appreciated:

```
- name: publish
  image: plugins/ecr
  pull: if-not-exists
  priveleged: true
  volumes:
  - name: build
    path: /root/.build
  settings:
    access_key: <ACCESS_KEY>
    secret_key: <SECRET_KEY>
    repo: my-repo
    dockerfile: dist/Dockerfile
    region: us-west-1
    registry: <ECR_REGISTRY>
    tags:
      - ${DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER}
      - latest
```